# Angular js (want output for this code)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Filtering input:

  {{ (x.name | uppercase) + ', ' + x.country }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Try

```
 {{ x.name | uppercase }} , {{ x.country }}
```

Comment: thanks for your quick response       since iam not getting X.name value in uppercase letter